# Objective-C Cocoa WebView path to local files

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview

I have a webview in a desktop app, and I have loaded my html file. In the head of the html file, I link to javascript files, but it only works when those are remote files, I want it to work for other files in the resources folder. What is the path I should use? Is there some issue I am missing?

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>MyWebPage</title>
  <!-- this works -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://somewhereontheweb.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- this does not -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- this does not -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="./jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- this does not -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="./Resources/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  ...
```

My objective-c code for the webview in case it is relevant:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)aWebView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation 
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    if ([self requestIsLinkClick:actionInformation]) {
        if ([@"method" isEqual:[[request URL] scheme]]) {
            SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([[request URL] resourceSpecifier]);
            if ([prototypeDelegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
                [prototypeDelegate performSelector:selector];
            }
        }
        // [listener ignore];
    } // else {
        [listener use];
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a class for this purpose, surf here https://github.com/iStopped/iOS-Classes and go in SimpleWebView folder ;) but before read the readme ;)